# Can i create Role for only read permissions of product in magento 2 admin panel

Tags: magento2, admin-panel, rest-api, user-roles

I want to create admin user who is access only read the products in magento 2.
Can i create Role for only read permissions of product in magento 2 admin panel.

Comment: have you done this implementation

Answer (score -1):

If You want user role for rest Api then 
Please check this URL http://blog.i13websolution.com/magento-2-create-soaprest-api-user/

And 
If You want only for accessable for admin then please do like below
Logged in admin as a admin user 
and 
Click System ->Permissions section -> User Roles -> Add New Role 
And fill Role Information 
1. Name
                          2. Current Admin Password
And Choose Role Resources And 
 click on  "Products" check box and 
click "Save Role" Button

Please Check 
http://prntscr.com/jmfpcu and http://prntscr.com/jmfpu3

Comment: But  i need only read permission of products,not need edit or delete permissions.

Comment: You want to REST API or another  Admin user?

Comment: admin user @Jugal Kishor

Comment: hi, what is the solution for this?